# Git: after shell generates files on the live server, does git repo updates automatically?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm very new to version control systems and this part seems confusing.

I'm using a PHP framework (Symfony) and sometimes I need to generate modules, etc. - new files.

I do this with Putty by connecting to the live server.

But the generated files on the server won't automatically appear in the repo on git, will they?

What is the concept behind this?

Comment: Files/Projects won't be added to a source control tool automatically. The blog [Version Control How To](http://version-control.net/) may help you get a general idea of what is version control and how to version control your projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files won't be added to your repository without interaction.  Everything that goes into your repository will need to be manually added with `git add fileName`